# save an image to sftp remote server sent by user

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh2

I want to upload a file to sftp remote server using ssh2-sftp-client. I am taking the file from user in a post request along with destination. I am using multer to process the file.

```
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const sftp = new Client();
const Multer = require("multer")
const multer = Multer({
    storage: Multer.MemoryStorage
});

app.put("/sftp", multer.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    sftpCredentials = req.query;
    sftp.connect({
        host: sftpCredentials.host,
        port: sftpCredentials.port,
        username: sftpCredentials.username,
        password: sftpCredentials.password
    }).then(res =>{
      sftp.put(req.file,req.query.destination);
    })
})
```

I am getting error :

```
TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer
```

Comment: Please describe the problem that you are facing. If there is an error which you get, paste the exact error text in your post

Comment: I am facing this error TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer

Answer (score 0):

```
sftp.put(localfilepath, remoteFilepath)
```

for localfilepath use:

```
req.file.path
```

You have used "req.file" only. If you want to get the filename too, use: req.file.originalname

Second, make sure "req.query.destination" is giving you the destination path where you want to put file.

And, do use of logging. It makes life easier.

Comment: req.file is an object which contains = 
`{
   buffer:Buffer(85967) [137, 80, 78, …]
   encoding:"7bit"
   fieldname:"file"
   mimetype:"image/png"
   originalname:"sample.png"
   size:85967
}`

Comment: Well, I put answer from one of my code where I used multer.
And, if you see official documentation of this module(https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), See API section. You can see that "path" is there which denotes local filepath.